# Ошибка при использовании модуля auto-py-to-exe

Tags: python, консоль, auto-py-to-exe

Я через `pip` установил `auto-py-to-exe`, после запустил `auto-py-to-exe.py` из папки пайтона \Scripts, программа запустилась. Но. Запустилась бесконечная анимация Инициализации:

[image]

А так же в консоль вывелась следующая ошибка:

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "src\\gevent\\greenlet.py", line 906, in gevent._gevent_cgreenlet.Greenlet.run File "C:\Users\xomnr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\eel\__init__.py", line 259, in _process_message return_val = _exposed_functions[message['name']](*message['args']) File "C:\Users\xomnr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\auto_py_to_exe\ui.py", line 46, in initialise 'warnings': utils.get_warnings(), File "C:\Users\xomnr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\auto_py_to_exe\utils.py", line 84, in get_warnings if sys.version_info.major == 3 and sys.version_info.minor == 10 and sys.version.micro == 0: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'micro' 2022-01-09T13:25:01Z <Greenlet at 0x2635f587be0: _process_message({'call': 1.7474922400639503, 'name': 'initialise',, <geventwebsocket.websocket.WebSocket object at 0x0)> failed with AttributeError`

Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Ну там явно ошибка в коде. Должно быть не `sys.version.micro`, а `sys.version_info.micro`, авторы библиотеки исправили вчера код, чтобы избежать ошибки при использовании python 3.10.0 и не протестировали. Попробуйте исправить это в `auto_py_to_exe\utils.py` (полный путь указан в ошибке у вас там).

Comment: Огромное спасибо, сделал как вы и сказали и проблема исправлена. @CrazyElf

Comment: Тогда добавлю в виде ответа эту инфу, вдруг кому ещё пригодится

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по [репозиторию](https://github.com/brentvollebregt/auto-py-to-exe/tree/master/auto_py_to_exe), авторы этой библиотеки вчера внесли изменение, чтобы избежать ошибок работы библиотеки с определённой версией питона и при этом занесли новый баг:

```
utils.py
#215 - Add warning when using Python 3.10.0
yesterday
```

В файле `auto_py_to_exe\utils.py` (полный путь можно посмотреть в тексте ошибки) нужно исправить явную описку:

```
sys.version.micro
```

Поменять на:

```
sys.version_info.micro
```